# fontspec: only-xetex-feature warning HyphenChar

Tags: fontspec

Since the latest update of `fontspec` to version 2.6d (2017/08/14) I receive several warnings. Have a look at the MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

If compiled via `lualatex`, the following warning is produced:

```
*************************************************          
* fontspec warning: "only-xetex-feature"                   
*                                                          
* Ignored XeTeX only feature: 'HyphenChar'.                
*************************************************
```

I cannot judge if this is a warning I should take care of, or if I can neglect it. The warning did not appear before the update. The warning is also produced in conjunction with the lucida OT fonts. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: It is not serious but Will made a change (I saw the announcement) but  forgot to adjust the \defaultfontfeatures for ttfamily in fontspec.cfg. Make a bug report https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer — thanks for this. I missed that \hyphenchar=-1 (only) is still supported in LuaTeX

Comment: I use XeTeX to compile, to still  can see this warning. By the way, the font name should be *TeX Gyre Cursor* with capital X.